# Does order matter in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

My robots.txt is following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /user/*
Disallow: /invitations/*
Disallow: /api/*

#Adsense crawler
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
```

Is the "Mediapartners-Google" crawler really allowed to scan all the pages?
Or the first line of my robots.txt `User-agent: *` will be preventing all crawlers (including "Mediapartners-Google") from accessing mentioned roots above even if there are following lines in the end of file:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
```

In other words - is order of rules matters in robots.txt - like in my situation?

Answer (score 6):

It seems i have found the answer. 
And the answer is - order does not matters, because:

> In a robots.txt file with multiple user-agent directives, each
>   disallow or allow rule only applies to the useragent(s) specified in
>   that particular line break-separated set. If the file contains a rule
>   that applies to more than one user-agent, a crawler will only pay
>   attention to (and follow the directives in) the most specific group of
>   instructions.

Source: https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt

Answer (score 1):

Order does not matter and you can test it by using Search console in robots section.
Change the order and test few pages, see if any thing is strange.